# Generating vectors in the span of two given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

List five vectors in Span $\{v1,v2\}$. For each vector, show the weights on $\mathbf v1$ and $\mathbf v2$ used to generate the vector and list the three entries of the vector. Do not make a sketch.

$$ {\mathbf v1} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\0  \\2 \\ \end{bmatrix}, {\mathbf v2} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\0  \\3 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

I do not really understand what it means by weights I assume in might mean multiplication.  I think the answer is:

$$v3 =\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0  \\5 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$ Since I assume that you add them. How does one choose their weights?

Comment: Why did you edit my title there was so much potential towards it :(

Comment: Your title had nothing to do with your question, and would have been useless for anyone trying to search for an answer to that question.  That's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know the term weights in this context, but it is likely to mean the multiples $w_i$ of the spanning vectors $v_i$:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{span}{Span}
\span\{v_1, v_2\} = \{ w_1 v_1 + w_2 v_2 \mid w_1, w_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Note: In other contexts, like linear optimization, there might be conditions imposed on those weight factors, e.g. $w_i \ge 0$ or $\sum_i w_i = 1$.

The resulting linear combinations would have special names, the first would result in conical combinations, all of them forming the conical hull, the second in affine combinations (affine hull), if both apply it results in convex combinations (convex hull).

Answer (score 2):

Choose five pairs of scalars, $\{ a_1, a_2 \}$, and create the set of vectors consisting of $a_1 {\mathbf v1} + a_2 {\mathbf v2}$ using each such pair.

Comment: I do not understand what are the criteria for choosing these scalars? Can they be anything?

Comment: Yep.  Indeed anything.  Think of the *span* of two vectors as the plane defined by those two vectors.  Any other vector in that plane (including the two generating vectors) lies in the span.  I think your teacher discouraged you from drawing a plane just to make you think abstractly.  If *I* were your teacher, I would have demanded you draw a picture.  They you would truly understand.

Comment: To show you understand this, you can even take a1, a2 to both be 0, have 1 value 0 and the other anything, be negative, be fractions or even real.

Comment: READ THE QUESTION.  You choose a vector in the *span* (e.g., {-2, 0, 16}) and *for that vector*, state the corresponding terms $a_1$ and $a_2$.  In this case: $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 4$.